# Host.json settings being ignored for Service Bus in Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, servicebus

I have the following in my host.json file for ServiceBus

```
"extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
        "prefetchCount": 10,
        "messageHandlerOptions": {
            "autoComplete": false,
            "maxConcurrentCalls": 10,
            "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:05:00"
        },
        "sessionHandlerOptions": {
            "autoComplete": false,
            "messageWaitTimeout": "00:00:30",
            "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:55:00",
            "maxConcurrentSessions": 10
        },
        "batchOptions": {
            "maxMessageCount": 1000,
            "operationTimeout": "00:01:00",
            "autoComplete": false
        }
    }
}
```

Note that autoComplete is always false

I then deployed my function to deliberately throw an exception in the handler

My subscription has a lock of 30 seconds and a max delivery count

I would expect this message to retry 10 times then get dead lettered

This doesn't happen

However, when I do this in code, it does work

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    base.Configure(builder);

    var services = builder.Services;

    builder.Services.Configure(delegate(ServiceBusOptions options)
    {
        options.MessageHandlerOptions.AutoComplete = false;
        options.SessionHandlerOptions.AutoComplete = false;
        options.BatchOptions.MaxMessageCount = 10;
        options.MessageHandlerOptions.MaxConcurrentCalls = 10;
        options.SessionHandlerOptions.MaxConcurrentSessions = 10;
    });
 }
```

What have I done wrong?  How can I verify if host.config has been ignored?

This issue happens on both development functions and the deployed version

I am using Azure Functions version 2

I have seen complicated fixes for host.config settings being ignored, but I am not sure that is relevant here, as they seem to be more for local scenarios whereas I get this on the deployed function as well

I am using the following for my config setup

```
public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
{
    var kvEndpoint =
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUP__KEYVAULT__CONFIGURATIONVAULT");
    builder.ConfigurationBuilder
        .AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri(kvEndpoint!), new DefaultAzureCredential())
        .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
}
```

Cheers

Paul

Comment: If you have `[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]` in your code, removing that should recognize `host.json` correctly.

Comment: I cant do that because then my startup logic wont run?

Comment: Is there any way to check for def if these are being ignored?

Comment: Hello @Paul, Any update to the issue?